# Chern-Weil homomorphism and Chern/Pontryagin/Euler class

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, de-rham-cohomology

I am reading Chapter on characteristic classes from Foundations of Differential geometry by Kobayashi and Nomizu. This chapter starts with concept of Chern-Weil homomorphism.

Given a Lie algebra $G$ with $\mathfrak{g}$ as its Lie algebra and a principal $G$ bundle $P(M,G)$ chern Weil homomorphism is a map from $I(G)\rightarrow H^*(M,\mathbb{R})$ where $I(G)$ is the algebra of symmetric multilinear mappings on $\mathfrak{g}$ invariant by $G$ and $H^*(M;\mathbb{R})$ is the deRham cohomology algebra on $M$.  This they define fixing a connection and then proves this map is independent of choice of connection. I am able to understand this.

Can some one help me to understand how this Chern-Weil homomorphism is involved in understanding about chern/Pontryagin/Euler classes? Any reference that explains motivation on these characteristic classes is also welcome. I am aware of Milnor’s book.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is to remark that because the Chern-Weil map $w:I(G)\to H^*(M,\mathbb{R})$ is independent of the connection chosen, the image of *any* invariant polynomial $f\in I(G)$ is a characteristic class of the bundle. Basically, given an isomorphism of principal bundles, the chosen connection on your initial induces a connection on your new bundle; the two so-induced Chern-Weil morphisms agree, so they must agree on $f$. Having said this, you can see that the optimal strategy is just to take generators for the polynomial ring on $\mathfrak{g}$ (i.e., $I(G)$).

Now, the characteristic classes you mention are precisely very good choices of generators for that ring. For example, for complex vector bundles, you consider $\mathrm{Gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, and note that the $c_i$ in the expression

$\begin{equation}
\det (I-\frac{1}{2\pi i}tX)=1+c_1(X)t+....+c_n(X)t^n
\end{equation}$

generate the ring of polynomials on $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{C})$, and therefore their evaluation at the curvature will generate the image of $I(\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ through the Weil homomorphism. These are precisely the Chern classes of the bundle.

A good book where all this is explained is [Morita's](https://books.google.es/books/about/Geometry_of_Differential_Forms.html?id=5N33Of2RzjsC&redir_esc=y). A good short answer on the motivation of this definition is Henry Horton's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523022/intuition-of-chern-weil-theory?rq=1); if you have (lot's) of time, you can look up Spivak's A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, especial [volume 3](https://books.google.es/books?id=-lXvAAAAMAAJ&q=spivak%20comprehensive%20volume%203&dq=spivak%20comprehensive%20volume%203&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm69C7gfHYAhWMPxQKHZgiAP8Q6AEIKjAA)'s Chapter 6 and [volume 5](https://books.google.es/books?id=flXvAAAAMAAJ&q=spivak%20comprehensive%20volume%205&dq=spivak%20comprehensive%20volume%205&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJqPjzgfHYAhXHvhQKHVnxBJ8Q6AEIJzAA)'s Chapter 13

Comment: NI am confused, do you mean definition of characteristic class of a bundle is image of an invariant polynomial under chern Weil map? Having said this, you can see that the optimal strategy is just to take generators for the polynomial ring on  is also not clear... I am seeing Morita’s book as well :)

Comment: Yes, the usual characteristic classes are evaluations of the Chern-Weil map at invariant polynomials. Taking generators is "optimal" in the sense that any other class can be written in terms of them, and it will be a minimal set of such.